# DO loop for proc compare with multiple libraries SAS

Tags: sas, macros, proc-sql

I have an excel with a column of files and another column with folder paths. I want to loop through the file paths and assign them libnames.

The excel:

```
file_name           file_path

file1.txt           filepath1
file2.sas7bdat      filepath1
file3.xlsx          filepath2
file4.txt           filepath3
file5.sas7bdat      filepath3
```

I found this solution, however, I have some files that come from the same folder and would like to assign the same libname to the same folder paths

```
data want;
set excel_table;
libref = 'LIBR' || put(_n_, Z4.);
rc = libname(libref, file_name,, "access=readonly');
if rc ne 0 then sysmsg = sysmsg();
run;
```

Could I add a "if.first.filepath..." type of statement?

The same files in column "file_name" are all also in another folder, Folder A. I eventually want to compare the files in the column "file_name" to that are in various other folders to the same files in Folder A. How can I first loop through the libnames and the associated files into a proc compare?

```
proc compare base = "dynamic libname".file_name compare=folder2.filename;
run;
```

Comment: LIBREFs are only for SAS datasets.  So only make librefs for those.  You could make FILEREFs for the other files.  Either one for each individual file. Or one that points to the directory which you can use in code like `infile filr0001("file1.txt");`

Comment: With PROC COMPARE you need two datasets to be compared. What do you want to compare?  Shouldn't the list have two datasets names on each row so you know what comparison to generate?

Comment: Folder A contains identical files as the files in the excel @Tom Thats what I'm comparing to ensure they are the same

Comment: Do you want to check the NAMES are the same? Or that the values in the datasets are the same?  It sounds like you do not need to generate librefs at all (unless you don't know the actual folder names in advance) instead you just need two librefs.

Comment: These files listed in the excel are in various different folders in SAS. I just put them down in a excel because these are the file I need to compare. These files exist in Folder A. I would like to compare all differences. Everything that a proc compare does @Tom

Comment: thank you, you're answer is super helpful! How can I try this with .txt and .xlsx files? @Tom

Comment: How do you want to compare such file?

Comment: Can I somehow put the tables in a macro variable, then do a %sysinfo > 0 for the ones that are different? I want to use the tables that are different @Tom

Answer (score 1):

Librefs point to directories, not files.  So assuming you have a dataset named HAVE that has those two columns then you will want to make one libref per FILE_PATH and not per FILE_NAME.  Librefs are only useful for accessing datasets.   So sort the HAVE dataset by FILE_PATH and you can use it to generate a list of datasets and also create a libref for each path with a step like this:

```
data ds_list;
  set HAVE ;
  by file_path;
  where lowcase(scan(file_name,-1,'.')) = 'sas7bdat';
  length libnum 8 libref $8 memname $32 rc 8 sysmsg $200 ;
  memname = scan(file_name,1,'.');
  if first.file_path then do;
    libnum + 1;
    libref = 'LIBR' || put(_n_, Z4.);
    rc = libname(libref, file_path,, 'access=readonly');
    if rc ne 0 then sysmsg = sysmsg();
  end;
run;
```

Now that you have defined one or more librefs (and importantly stored the generated libref names into a dataset) you can use them in your PROC COMPARE code.

But it is not at all clear what dataset(s) you want to compare them TO.

If the goal is just to compare the datasets to the datasets in "folder A" then that should be simple.  You could use a step like this to generate one PROC COMPARE for every dataset in you list that has a matching dataset in A.

```
libname A 'folder A';
data _null_;
   set ds_list;
   if exists(cats('A.',memname)) and exists(catx('.',libref,memname)) then 
     call execute(catx(' ','proc compare data=',cats('A.',memname)
                 ,'compare=',catx('.',libref,memname),';run;'
     ))
   ;
   else put 'NOTE: No match found for ' memname= file_path= file_name= ;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare the files found in "Folder A" to the files listed in your worksheet you will need to retrieve the filenames from "Folder A" into a data set and also read the worksheet as a data set (xlsx engine).

Example:

```
libname base xlsx ".../path-to-workbook.xlsx";
proc sort data=base.sheet1 out=work.workbook_list;
  by file_name;
run;

filename folder ".../path-to/Folder A";
data folder_listing(keep=file_name);
  did = dopen("folder");
  length file_name $3000;
  if did then
   do index=1 to dnum(did);
     file_name = dread(did,index);
     output;
   end;
run;

data _null_;
  merge workbook_list(in=base) folder_listing(in=compare);
  by file_name;
  if base and not compare then put 'in excel not in A ' file_name;
  else
  if not base and compare then put 'not in excel in A ' file_name;
  else
                               put 'in excel and in A ' file_name;
run;
```